# Spark Scala: Failed to execute user defined function Caused by: SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration

Tags: scala, dataframe, user-defined-functions, databricks, word2vec

I have a dataframe with one column that contains string, and I need to use Word2Vec model to add synonyms to that word in a new column.

So I wrote this function:

```
    def expand(word: String): String = {
      val model = Word2VecModel.load( "w2vec.model")
      val expanded = model.findSynonyms(word,3).rdd.map(_.getString(0)).collect().toList.mkString(" ")
      expanded
    }
```

When I call the function, I get

```
expand("usb")
res51: String = hdmi cable kabel
```

Cool so far, now I want to put this function in a udf and apply it to an entire dataframe:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val func = udf(expand _)
val exploded_df_w2vec = exploded_df.withColumn("expanded", func($"col"))
```

The problem appears here:

```
display(exploded_df_w2vec)
Failed to execute user defined function($read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$6261/1609460357: (string) => string)
Caused by: SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

This code is executed in databricks, Scala 2.12
Any idea how to work around this issue?

Comment: got any luck? been having same issue